# How to Lazy Load child Component in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular6, lazy-loading, angular8, angular9

I have a component that contain multiple modal(NgbModal).These modals connect to multiple child components.I'm trying to lazy load these child component

```
Dashboard Module  
    |  
    |--> Dashboard Component   
            |-->modal 1  
                 |  
                 |--> child 1 component
                 |--> child 2 component
            |--modal 2
                 |--> child 3 component
                 |--> child 4 component
```

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score 0):

You can lazy load the dashboard module by using routes like this

```
// in app routing or higher routing module than dashboard
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => 
  import('./modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule) },
];
```

Then inside your dashboards routing moldule(To be imported in dahsboard module) you can further repeat the same procedure to lazy load child modules/component or else you could directly route the child component.

```
// in dashboard routing module
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'chilldComponent1', loadChildren: () => 
  import('./modules/dashboard/components/chilldComponent1.module').then(m => 
  m.chilldComponent1Module) },
 { path: 'childcomponent2', component: Childcomponent2},

];
```